# jquery inputmask não aceita quantificador na função "validator"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, jquery-validate

Estou tentando fazer um customAlias para usar com o jQuery Inputmask, mas estou enfrentando o seguinte problema:

**Meu input:**

`<input id="input-field-nome" data-inputmask="'alias':'customAlias'" type="text" data-rule-required="true" class="form-control required" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome">`

**Javascript:**

```
 Inputmask.extendAliases({
    'customAlias': {
      autoUnmask: true,
      placeholder: "",
      mask: "a",
      definitions: { "a" : { validator: "[a-zA-Z]+" } }
    }
  });

  //initializing the plugin
  $(":input").inputmask({
    placeholder: ''
  });
```

Eu entendi que a linha `validator: "[a-zA-Z]+"` deveria funcionar da seguinte maneira: 'qualquer letra **uma ou mais vezes**, mas o quantificador `+` não está funcionando. Eu apenas consigo inserir uma letra no campo.

Eu tentei as seguintes formas, mas nenhuma resolveu:

`"validator": "[a-zA-Z\+]",` - Vi algo desse tipo na página de exemplos do plugin.

`"validator": "[a-zA-Z]\+",` - Achei que escapar o + seria a solução, mas não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uma solução simples é adicionar o atributo repeat à sua definição

```
Inputmask.extendAliases({
    'customAlias': {
      autoUnmask: true,
      placeholder: "",
      mask: "a",
      repeat: 100, // tamanho máximo do campo
      definitions: { "a" : { validator: "[a-zA-Z]" } }
    }
  });
```

Somente acho que esqueceu de que deve ser permitido aceitar espaços, então eu mudaria a máscara para `[a-zA-Z\s]`

Comment: +1 e segue o [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/vwooLp2v/5/) =D

Comment: Boa @MarcosRegis, isso soluciona meu problema. Por questão de curiosidade, você sabe porque na regex do validator não posso usar nenhum quantificador? Tentei '+', '*', '{1, 10}', '{10}' e nada. Seria ótimo se  funcionasse

Comment: curiosamente, aqui no meu local, apenas com \s funcionou. Já no fiddle precisei usar \\s

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos Eu não uso esse plugin (também uso máscaras, porém uso outro plugin) e não sei exatamente o motivo. Aparentemente ele não usa o validator como uma regex de fato. Apenas aceita os qualificadores para então formar o regex final.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado! :)